# How to improve acceptance of my questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've asked already two questions on this site.

As of now [one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92166/manage-unhelpful-it-manager) has a balance of -2, and the [other](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/124889/handling-no-response-from-team-members?noredirect=1#comment396170_124889) is 0 (2 up and 2 down votes as I can see).

I feel I put reasonable effort asking the questions, did read "how to ask" before each questions, being responsive to comments and try to improve my questions.

I've received good answers, so I'm happy, but also I'm a bit disappointed seeing they are not well received.

How could I do better?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is well over a year old now and isn't likely to gain votes now unless there's something that necessitates an update to the question.

I see there are a few delete comments asking for clarification, which you've given.  I'm guessing there's a balance of -2 votes because people might see this question as more of a complaint against your IT help desk rather than being a question seeking a goal that can be addressed.

You have an answer, which gained up-votes, and you've marked that as being accepted.

Your second question is relatively new (at 150 views), and you have an even balance there (at time of writing).  Bear in mind that you may get some downvoting because you're essentially chasing information that isn't yet due (or at least that's the impression of the question).  You've clearly defined what goals you have for the question, so it could be a matter of time before you get some more views (most users here seem to come from the USA).

Answer (score -7):

I downvoted both questions because your questions were too long and complicated to read.

This website encourages a downvote if the question is ".... unclear or not useful ...". It was not clear what you tried to achieve in your questions. Your downvotes were justified.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I tried to include all relevant information what I thought needed to understand my situation. Do you have any specific suggestion how to improve them?  I know I'm not good in this field otherwise I wouldn't ask these questions.

Comment: If you find a question long or complicated to understand, please refrain from voting or affecting it in any way. Maybe come back at a later time, but in any case leave it to those people who do read and understand it. I do the same. This ensures we are at our best when reading and responding to questions.